# JavaScript data grid for millions of rows AND columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, datagrid, grid

I am looking for a component where I can present not only millions of rows but also a lot of columns (up to 100000). I am not looking for answers in the form of "Why would you that?". I know slickgrid can represent millions of rows, but does not manage the virtualization of columns. Columns are not treated as rows and when you have too many columns (more than 150 rows) slickgrid gets buggy and slow.

Can anybody suggest such a component which will process not only heavy vertical scrolling but horizontal scrolling as well? Not only rows, but columns as well?

Comment: I'm not going to ask why you would want that, but I must ask who on earth would use it...

Comment: I am totally interested on reading millions of rows. I think it will be fun and relaxing

Comment: It is not about the fun and the supposed therapeutic effects - it is about implementing the scroll listeners efficiently. But I do agree - I loaded a million rows and boy was it relaxing ... :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not jQuery, but QooXDoo's grid is supposed to be capable of quite a bit of heavy-lifting. Of course, I cannot testify in its favor, since I haven't actually used it.

http://qooxdoo.org/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at YUI's ScrollingDataTable: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.ScrollingDataTable.html

"The ScrollingDataTable class extends the DataTable class to provide functionality for x-scrolling, y-scrolling, and xy-scrolling."

Answer (score -1):

You should give a try to [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid):

> A lightning fast JavaScript grid/spreadsheet

Comment: He explicitly stated that he doesn't want to use SlickGrid ...